# How do I handle the click of an array of EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a little problem with my app. In my app dynamically  I create a table of EditText, obtaining an array of EditText, at this point would like to draw, when I click on the EditText my Keyboard instead of that of default. How do I handle the click of an array of EditText?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
for(int i=0; i<etArray.lenght; i++) {
    etArray[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```